# Programming principle for accessing view from fragment to activity's views

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity and a fragment inside it.
Main activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    android:text="Login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

After replace a fragment to fl_content by:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_conent, new MyFragment());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

From MyFragment, I want cho change text/color of btn_login, from my knowledge I can:
The first way, from inside MyFragment:

```
Button btnLogin = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
btnLogin.setText("Another text");
```

This way I think the fragment should not access activity's login button (and any other acitivty's view if have any even if we can) because it violate encapsulation or loose-coopling in programming.

The second way: create a Listener/Callback

```
public interface ChangeListener {
    void onChanged();
}
```

then set it to fragment, from activity I implement this listener

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
myFragment.setOnChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onChanged() {
         btnLogin.setText("Another text");
     }
}
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_conent, myFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Whenever I need to change btnLogin text, from MyFragment I just call `mChangeListener.onChanged();`
then activity will change it's btnLogin by itshelf. This way keep encapsulation - loose-coopling.

I think we should use the second way, or may be another way that not listed here, how about you? I am glad to hear your opinion.
Thanks!

@Jim Coven: what is "startActivityForResults from the Activity, then use setResults in the fragment". Could you give me some code snippet to understand this :D

Comment: will prefer second way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer the 2nd way. However, that will still require an external call to set the listener. Alternatively, if the fragment's purpose is to update results in the Activity, you could try:

startActivityForResults from the Activity, then use setResults in the fragment.